# c# Получение публичных свойств из экземпляра класса с помощью рефлексии

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Всем привет.

Пишу метод для логирования, с помощью которого можно было-бы получить все публичные свойства экземпляра класса и вывести их в файл.

```
public static string PropertiesToString<T>(T instanse)
{
    var properties = instanse.GetType().GetProperties();
    var result = properties.Select(x => $"{x.Name}: {x.GetValue(instanse, null)}");
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
}
```

Всё-бы отлично, но в некоторых классах у меня используются List и Dictionary (из которого нужно только Value). Можно ли так же с помощью рефлексии получить публичные свойства или придётся для каждого отдельного класса писать отдельный метод?

Comment: `File.WriteAllText("file.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(instance));` - и готово, всё уже в файле, безо всяких наворотов.

Comment: да, можно. идея в том, что все контейнеры реализуют небольшое кол-во стандартных интерфейсов. вот для [примера](https://github.com/miptleha/cs-obj-compare/blob/master/Comparer.cs), я реализовал сравнение в глубину двух произвольных объектов (сравнение делается и по непубличным свойствам, так что у вас задача проще).

Comment: Точно! Совершенно забыл о сериализации. Спасибо

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Интересная реализация. Думал тоже о примерно подобном - определять тип свойства и, если это NN тип, то углубляться в него, но совершенно забыл о сериализации. Воспользуюсь, наверное, ею, т.к. это гораздо проще и избавляет от тонны кода :)

Comment: Я, наверное, всё же попробую реализовать по аналогии с вашим примером и добавлю свой код в ответ. Вдруг кому-нибудь в будущем поможет. Будет отличной практикой по рефлексии, а то давненько не трогал её

Comment: Используйте сериализацию, не выдумвайте велосипедов, это ни кому не поможет, а скорее собьет с толку. Вы по факту пытаетесь написать свой сериализатор. 1) зачем? 2) кто сказал, что он будет работать быстрее?

Comment: Хм, ну, хорошо. Единственное, я чаще пользуюсь JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance, Formatting.Indented). Не знаю, какая разница между System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer

Comment: Разница в том, что Newtonsoft.Json использовался до появления System.Text.Json в старых фреймворках. Оба сериализатора хорошие, но необходимости отдельно устанавливать нугет пакет теперь нет. Если конечно вы на свежем .NET. А еще последний работает немного быстрее. Используйте `@aepot` в комментарии, если ко мне обращаетесь, я не вижу сейчас уведомлений о ваших вопросах.